# UTF-8 Encoding not working on Heroku with Static Build

Tags: heroku, utf-8, middleman

I'm using a static site generator (Middleman) to build my site. I'm using a buildpack with Heroku so that the site gets built and then hosted as a static site with some rack middleware when I push my codebase to the site. Locally my encoding shows up fine but on Heroku it pukes. I've tried setting the LANG variable through the Console and still nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.